# How to attach Bitmaps to a MovieClip in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a bunch of Bitmaps stored in the library and I want to display some of them on the stage via actionscript. All I need is to attach each of them to a MovieClip and use addChild() on the stage. Also I want to be able change the attached bitmaps dynamically.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new LibraryBitmapInstance(null, null));
// Add
myMovieclip.addChild(myBitmap);
// remove
myMovieclip.removeChild(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Note, you'll need to make sure the Bitmap is marked for "Export for ActionScript", which can be set in the properties panel of the bitmap instance in the library.  All the arguments in the constructor are optional as well, so you could just say "new LibraryBitmapInstance()".